# How to configure AWS cloudWatchAgent to collect logs recursively from a folder on an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a `logs` directory on a EC2 instance and cloud watch agent running over there. In the CloudWatch agent configuration file I have given log file details as below

```
"logs": {
    "logs_collected": {
      "files": {
        "collect_list": [
          {
            "file_path": "/home/ec2-user/logs/**/*",
            "log_group_name": "test0",
            "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

but this is not collecting logs recursively. I want cloud agent to send all the logs present under one directory(having nested directories as well) to cloud watch logs.
How is that possible?

Answer (score 10):

The first ** wildcard is all you need to pick up all logs in all sub-directories:

`"file_path": "/home/ec2-user/logs/**",`

Alternatively you can pick up a specific log file in all sub-directories with:

`"file_path": "/home/ec2-user/logs/**/mylogfile.log",`

It looks like the additional * wildcard on the end of your file_path is causing the issue.

Comment: does this work ?

Comment: Is there any way to preserve the directory structure?